# Why does this video make me feel nostalgic?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I stumbled upon this video in a website:
https://9gag.com/gag/aM8ELMP#comment

Just as the video post title says, it makes me feels really nostalgic. Is the title deceiving viewers to feel nostalgic? or is it the video that actually causes nostalgia?

Are there visual (and other sensory) methods, like these, to create a nostalgic feeling in humans?

[image: snapshot from video]

Comment: Hi Nikpod, welcome at CogSci. The way you phrased your question, makes it look like a question of individual behavior and a bit opinion based (that is, it appears to be not based on scientific observations). I am not able to formulate a good answer, but a quick google search showed an article how movies influences tourism: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Bolan/publication/266280324_DISPLACEMENT_THEORY_-_PROBING_NEW_GROUND_IN_FILM-INDUCED_TOURISM/links/54ae514d0cf2213c5fe43f5c/DISPLACEMENT-THEORY-PROBING-NEW-GROUND-IN-FILM-INDUCED-TOURISM.pdf . I hope this paper may explain some.